# How can space be euclidean when light bends?

Tags: general-relativity, visible-light, spacetime, curvature

I have read people arguing that tridimensional space sections of space time continuum (whatever its number of dimensions) appears to be euclidean from empirical evidence. I cannot reconcile it with my understanding that

1. Mass does exist
2. Mass does curve the spacetime continuum and 3D space sections
3. light bending has been explained by spacetime curvature.

Comment: The theory of spacetime and of its curvature is General Relativity (GR). In GR, spacetime is a *manifold*, which is a geometrical object that **locally** looks like $\mathbb{R}^3$, i.e. Euclidean space. I don't know about specific experimental evidence, but they should agree with this.

Comment: I think it is fair to say that the question is not valid because space is not Euclidean in general.

Answer (score 2):

It takes time for light to bend, i.e. the bending of light is a consequence of the curvature of geodesics in four dimensional space-time. On the other hand, a three dimensional snapshot of space appears to have geodesics that are straight lines (some specifics shown below). This is exactly why we thought space was Euclidean for so long and why all Earth-bound experiments on a local scale mesh well with the hypothesis of Euclidean geometry.

Take, for example, the Schwarzschild metric of space-time around a spherical mass (taken from Wikipedia):

$$
ds^2 = \left( 1 - \frac{r_s}{r} \right) dt^2 - \left( 1 - \frac{r_s}{r} \right)^{-1} dr^2 - r^2 \left( d \theta^2 + \sin^2 \theta d \phi^2 \right)
$$

For $r \gg r_s$, the spatial component of this metric is simply

$$
dl^2 = -ds^2 \mid_{dt = 0} = dr^2 + r^2 \left( d \theta^2 + \sin^2 \theta d \phi^2 \right)
$$

which is just the 3-dimensional Euclidean metric in spherical coordinates. Of course, this is only approximately Euclidean (and the approximation breaks down for $r \sim r_s$), but it was enough to fool us all until Einstein.

So, this should be pretty easy to reconcile with empirical evidence. Just go look at things, and ask yourself "High school geometry works pretty accurately, doesn't it?".

Comment: Thanks Jwimberley. First of two comments. I have difficulties with your first part. Indeed: Imagining an observer and a star sitting diametrally opposite respect to the Sun and the star’s light ray detected by the observer, I cannot help but imagine a light ray curved trajectory (projection on the sun celestial equatorial plane of the ray  movement in 4D timespace) – that is a 2D spatial geodesic which is curved in 2D space when simply observed from a 3D Euclidean space. Surely I am missing something. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks Jwimberley. Second of two comments. I have difficulties with your use of the Schwarzschild metric. First, I am interested in r of the order of rs – otherwise we have flat Minkowski space. Then, see for example P. Collier, A Most Incomprehensible Thing, p. 255,6,7 : For each fixed t, space is a foliation of spheres, true. Yet, since “r” is not “proper distance (radial)”, circles do not behave as in flat space: the proper spatial distance d between two spatial coplanar and concentric circumferences of lengths 2r and 2r+dr) is not dr but dr/√(1-2m/r).  Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry for character-loss: they were: spatial distance dsigma; lenghts 2 Pi r and 2 Pi (r+dr). Thanks.

Comment: @massimo You're making things way too complicated. The point is that although your understanding #2 is true, the curvature of 3D space is not much, except in extreme scenarios.  I also think you are misreading "appears to be Euclidean" - this is saying that space is approximately Euclidean, not exactly Euclidean, within the sensitivity of most experiments. One such experiment: Go measure the area of a triangle. Another: Send a probe to Pluto with a navigation system that assumes 3D space is Euclidean, as NASA does.

Comment: @massimo If you are interested in r of the order of rs (which is only a good model true for black holes, because the Schwarzschild solution is inappropriate inside the star, and in particular at the Schwarzschild radius which is much less than the radius of a star), then the approximately Euclidean nature of space breaks down. It is definitely a good approximation on moderate scales, away from black holes and areas of extreme curvature and smaller than Hubble scales at which the universe might show positive or negative curvature (though it appears flat even there).

Comment: Thanks Jwimberley. First comment of two. About Rs. Rs for the Sun is 3km. Sun’s R is 700k km. Rs/R circa 10exp(-6) which is not negligible (in proxy of Sun’s surface). Thks.

Comment: Thanks Jwimberley. Second comment of two. I have given up with measuring triangle to detect non Euclidean  For I have seen that: we only measure time intervals (of EW). Time is subject to special relativity and is also impacted by mass presence. Mass distribution is dealt with by perturbation theory. Exact mass values are unknown to us. Etc. It is therefore not possible to establish to which degree all these factors may offset/ interfere with calculation of the (very small) SPACE curvature. Thks.

Comment: @massimo I would say that corrections on the order of 10^-6 are pretty negligible for most purposes! Something that effects calculations in the 6th decimal place would have been hard to notice historically *even* if we could do experiments at the Sun's surface (not to say that an experiment that could measure this wouldn't be interesting and important)

Answer (score 2):

The statement that space is Euclidean is a broad statement, not meant to hold near very massive bodies or in arbitary volumes. One sense in which it can be meant is to hold "on average" for the whole spacetime - the universe - as such.

The best candidate for the overall metric of spacetime is the [FRLW metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLRW_metric), which is the exact solution for a universe that is homogenous and isotropic (looks the same at all points in all directions). On large scales, the homogeneity of the [Cosmic Microwave Background](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background) suggests this is a good approximation to our universe at large. It is written as

$$ \mathrm{d}s^2 =  - \mathrm{d}t^2 + a(t)^2\mathrm{d}\Sigma^2$$

modulo an overall sign and a factor of $c$ set to $1$, where $\mathrm{d}\Sigma^2$ is the metric of a three-dimensional space of uniform curvature. Now, there are three different kinds of space that could be - a hyperbolic (negative curvature), an elliptic (positive curvature) or an Euclidean (flat) space.

These are, effectively, distinguished by the way the angles in a triangle add up. Now, look at the space around you, on astronomical scales (so take a triangle out of stars). Observations by astronomers in this vein have found that there's no major indication that the *space* part of spacetime is curved on big scales (though locally, it may well be), though, due to experimental errors, we can of course only say that the curvature is very close to zero.

Another way to get to Euclidean space is to make a weak field approximation, i.e. being far from the Schwarzschild radius of a supermassive body.

Comment: Space can be made aribitrarily close to Minkowski(spatial part Euclidean) by choosing a small enough four-cube of spacetime.  So, sufficiently small volumes are, in a sense, exactly Euclidean.

Comment: Thanks ACuriousMind. You reported exactly the arguments that made me perplex, but you added a for me fundamental distiguo, "[...] there's no major indication that the space part of spacetime is curved on big scales (though locally, it may well be) [...]" by saying "though locally, it may well be" you made explicit my point: is it not already verified that locally space is curved, by the fact that the space trajectory of a star’s light ray is curved around the Sun? See also my reply to kind Jwimberley. Thanks again

Comment: @massimo The curvature of light around the sun is verification that *spacetime* is locally curved, not *space*. Of course space is curved, just not much.

Comment: @jwimberley, Thks, So, we can agree that SPACE is curved though "very little"?

Comment: My recap for your kind check: PART1. Geometry of Space - Locally: Our equations, e.g. Schwarzschild, tell us that SPACE is curved in the proximity of large masses. Yet, except for BH, curvature is too small to effectuate our experiments/ applications.

Comment: My recap for your kind check: PART2. Geometry of Space Globally: regardless of being it “slightly bumpy” locally, If I look at the entire Space, is it flat or curved (as a sphere or hyperboloid)? To this question we DO NOT HAVE equations and we can only say what it appears from observations: that it appears FLAT.

Comment: I wish to thk for the stimulating discussion and add my modest final comment. Our mathematical models (even as simple as Schwarzschild’s) tell us that locally space is curved, non Euclidean. At qualitative level, this makes a huge difference in our understanding of how radical and complex we may need to be to model the Universe. As for the quantitative aspects, they appear to be negligible 1. TODAY, but for sure they were not in the early stages of mass concentration of the Universe 2. Far from large bodies 3. For our current applications/ detection tools. Thks all

Comment: @massimo Yes, I think the statements in your  last three comments are all correct

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely correct that three-dimensional sections of space-time do not satisfy Euclidean geometry -- they are not flat. However, they are *almost* flat. On room-sized scales the curvature is very small indeed.

I don't know the exact context where you read that "tridimensional space sections of space time continuum (whatever its number of dimensions) appear to be Euclidean from empirical evidence," but I assume the writers were not claiming that spatial sections truly are Euclidean (in the sense of being flat), to the best of our understanding and to infinite precision. They only meant that such sections *appear* to be Euclidean when observed using simple methods.